# .NET5 Azure Function Service Bus Trigger Binding attributes

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, .net-5, azure-servicebus-queues

I am currently using `Micrsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus` package.

I want to be able to serialise the queueItem to my custom type and get message receiver, but unable to. How can I do it in .NET5 Azure Functions?

```
        [Function(nameof(Run))]
        public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("queuename", IsSessionsEnabled = true, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] QueueMessagePayload queueItem,
            MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
                string lockToken,
   FunctionContext context)
```

MessageRecevier does not exist (syntax error). I also get the following error if I specify custom type instead of string.

```
Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Diagnostics.Exceptions.FunctionInputConverterException: Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'Run': Cannot convert input parameter 'queueItem' to type 'QueueMessagePayload' from type 'System.String'
```

```
    [Serializable]
    public class QueueMessagePayload
    {
        public ActionEnum Action { get; set; }
        public Object Body { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Functions Isolated Worker SDK does not support SDK types for bindings.
Specifically for Azure Service Bus, you'd need to receive your message as a string or byte array and deserialize it into the custom type.

The following will help you to get more context:

- [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/226) about SDK types support for Azure Service Bus
- [Blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/functions-isolated-worker-sending-multiple-messages) on receiving (and sending multiple messages)